# Unable to deploy JAX-RS (Jersey 2.3.1) Web Service using Tomcat 6

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I am having a difficult time trying to figure how the issue I am having.  I couldn't deploy a JAX-RS web service that uses Jersey 2.3.1 on the Tomcat 6.

I use Eclipse 3.8.2 and deploy my Jersey 2.3.1 web service by clicking on my 'project -> Run As -> Run on Server'  I got the following exception.

```
Oct 08, 2013 3:42:29 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.3.1 2013-09-27 07:50:09...
Oct 08, 2013 3:42:29 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.WebTargetValueFactoryProvider] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 4
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientConfig
...
MultiException stack 4 of 4
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.WebTargetValueFactoryProvider
    contracts={org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ValueFactoryProvider}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@1c756a8
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=25
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=677756
    reified=false)
```

Any idea what could be wrong with my configuration?  Thanks!!

Comment: If you're using maven, and you've included the jar that contains org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig in your pom, make sure you don't have a scope of provided. If you do have scope of provided, make sure the jar that contains that class is in the tomcat/lib directory. And if neither of those is the case, could you post your pom perhaps? And are you sure it's deploying to the tomcat you think it is?

Answer (score 2):

It was a total mistake.  I forgot to add jersey-client.jar into my Eclipse project.

Comment: Yes, its quite wierd but jersey-client is required for jersey to function as of 2.3.1 this is noted here https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2104